# How can i create own order Time Countdown for EVERY ORDER

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status, datetime

I need to create `time Countdown for every order,` which is used to `priority to my pending order.` If order complete stop the countdown.  and how can I share my new order mail to multiple email addresses?

Comment: Is it possible create own order Time Countdown for EVERY ORDER

Comment: Can you explain more clearly or draw expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your 2nd question, **System > configuration > Sales > Sales emails**  and you can enter multiple email address in `Send Order Email Copy To` field.

[image]

Comment: make me one thing clear, the the money paid then only the mail send to desired mail right ??

Comment: @JeevaRathinam yes, for prepaid orders if money paid by customer , than only it will send email, for cash on delivery it will send automatically once order placed.

Comment: in my case, if order placed by cod, the mail not automatically send to customer, if i click to 'send mail' from backend then only customer get mail,